# Node.js is crashing/exiting without any error message in minified npm package, how to debug?

Tags: node.js, google-trends

I'm using a library `google-trends-api` and for some reason it's causing node to exit without any error. Just a clean errorless exit. The try/catch is ignored. I'm quite confused as this has never happened to me in 3 years of using node.

Here's the code, not that it matters much:

```
  let res
  try {
    res = await googleTrends.interestOverTime({
      keyword: ['something', keyword],
      geo: 'EN',
      startTime: new Date(getDaysAgoTimestamps(365)),
      agent: proxyAgent
    })
    debug({res})
    res = JSON.parse(res)
  }
  catch (e) {
    debug('getTrendsAverages error')
    debug(e)
  }
```

My question is, how can I even begin to debug this? I tried to look at the lib in node modules but it's minified.

Comment: How have you isolated the unexpected exit to this particular block of code in the first place if there's no error?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, if I mock `googleTrends.interestOverTime` the script finishes 50k iterations, if I don't it eventually terminates at ~100

Comment: Are you *sure* it's this library?  Or could it be some other part of your code that is interfering with this library (so that it fails when you use them together)?  The gootle trends API stuff is plain JS and pretty basic HTTP request code at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following error-handling functions as they will provide more detail about your problem.

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.log(reason)
})
process.on('uncaughtException', (reason) => {
    console.log(reason)
})
```